# routing issue with will paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have this route in my routes.rb

```
map.downloads 'downloads', :controller => 'assets', :action => 'index', :id => 'downloads'
```

this works fine. `<%=link_to 'downloads', downloads_path %>` takes me to

```
/downloads
```

as expected, but when I go to page the results using the will paginate plugin all the links generated look like

```
/assets/index/downloads
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because of the relative path of the route? Could you change "downloads" to "/downloads" and see if it works?

```
map.downloads '/downloads', :controller => 'assets', :action => 'index', :id => 'downloads'
```

Comment: tried that it didn't work ... its seems like the appearance of 'page' in the parameters throws off the route so it doesn't recognize it any longer

Comment: Oh. Does adding a :defaults => {:page => nil} to the route make a difference ?

Comment: It didn't, it caused the pages to error out with "ArgumentError: page: No matching segment exists; cannot assign default" ... thanks for that though, I didn't know about that little part of Rails routing. Let me know if you think of anything else

Comment: Also let me point out that when I do [map.downloads'/downloads/:page', :controller => 'assets', :action => 'index', :id => 'downloads', :page => nil] it works, but the urls look like this '/downloads/12', but I want them to look like this '/downloads?page=12

Comment: I figured it out [map.downloads '/downloads', :controller => 'assets', :action => 'index', :id => 'downloads', :pager => 'page=:page'] did the trick ... thanks for the inspiration :D !!!!